# JPA equivalent of Hibernate's join and subselect in mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate I can use `join` to map fields in an entity.

-- Example --

If I have the following class:

```
public class Order{

    private String orderNum;

    private String productName;
    private String productCost;

    private String recipientName;
    private String recipientAddress1; 
}
```

I can map that class with the following Hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="Order" table="order">

  <property name="orderNum" type="java.lang.long" column="order_num" />

  <join table="product">

    <subselect>
      SELECT o.order_id, p.name, p.cost
      FROM product p INNER JOIN order o ON o.product_id = p.product_id
    </subselect>

    <key column="order_id" />

    <property name="productName" type="java.lang.String" column="name" />
    <property name="productCost" type="java.lang.Double" column="cost" />

  </join>

  <join table="recipient">

    <subselect>
      SELECT o.order_id, r.name, r.address1
      FROM recipient r INNER JOIN order o ON o.recipient_id = r.recipient_id
    </subselect>

    <key column="order_id" />

    <property name="recipientName" type="java.lang.String" column="name" />
    <property name="recipientAddress1" type="java.lang.String" column="address1" />

  </join>
</class>
```

Are there JPA annotations that give the equivalent functionality?

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I'm looking for the same thing today, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. We needed to try this approach to solve a performance issue and ended up going a different route to solve our problem. This would have been a much better solution, though...

Comment: Acutally run into the same problem. Looking for a JPA equivalent for Hibernate's `@Subselect`.